# Android custom view only gets onDraw called once

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, rendering

i made a custom view which should animate a dot on a background according to some external data. (works like a charm with textviews)

view is then added in xml and android:background is set.

view gets rendered properly but does not update. some debugging revealed that onDraw only gets called once. what is missing?

code for my custom view:

```
 public class Gmeter extends ImageView {
    private Bitmap dot;
    private float dotHeight, dotWidth;

    public Gmeter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        dot = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.g_dot);
        dotWidth = dot.getWidth();
        dotHeight = dot.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float dataX =(float) Data.getX();

        float x = (getWidth()-dotWidth)/2f;
        float y = (getHeight()-dotHeight)/2f;

        x+= dataX * getWidth() /2f;

        canvas.drawBitmap(dot, x, y, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever is setting the `x` in `Data` needs to call `invalidate()` to tell the `View` that it needs to redraw based on new data. The `View` can't read your mind to know when new data is available :).

And definitely tie it to the data updating... if you call `invalidate()` from within your `onDraw()` you will have a great recipe for wasting CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best implementation because it will constantly update, but you can call:

```
invalidate();
```

in the onDraw() method and it will redraw.

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty easy to create a Runnable (with a Handler) that calls invalidate(); 16 times a second or so. Just place a handler.postDelay(this,delay); after calling invalidate(); to control the replay rate.